# How to limit the depth of lines per error in g++

Tags: c++, c++11, g++

I know I can set -fmax_errors to limit the number of errors before giving up... however what I would like is for each error message to be more succinct. Right now each error traces so far back through the source files that it is difficult to go through and figure out which lines are errors. I would like to have just the first line of each error outputted. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You could use `grep` to filter the lines to be more succinct.

Comment: The first line of each error has the word "Error"; subsequent lines are marked "Note". And you **do** need the notes; in template code, the cause of the error is often far away from the place where the compiler recognizes the problem. Reading error messages can be hard; it takes practice. What I like to do is limit the number of reported errors to 1 or possibly 2.

Comment: I can usually tell from the error line what the problem was and I never need to trace back ... so it's much better just to not have them adding noise to the signal. It is easier to have all the errors in one compile so you can go through and fix them one by one.